# XmlTextReader C# Problems With Reading and Writing

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

So, I am trying to make a "Recent Files" feature in my WPF application by use of C#'s XML class.

Basically, the program needs to read each  node and get the URI of file to generate menu item.

Problem is, r.Value doesn't give me a string to work with and I'm starting to question whether or not this code is going to work.

```
XmlTextReader r = new XmlTextReader(this.PathToSpecialFolder + @"\" + Application.CompanyName + @"\" + Application.ProductName + @"\Recent.xml");

int count = 0;
while (r.Read())
{
    switch (r.NodeType)
                {
        case XmlNodeType.Element:
            if (r.Name == "Path")
            {
                count++;
                if (count <= 5)
                {
                    MenuItem m = new MenuItem() { Header = r.Value };
                    openRecentMenuItem.Items.Add(m);
                    //r.Value populates nothing
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
r.Close();
```

On a related topic, I'm also trying to get it to where the XML file will only store five nodes. I want to...

1. Get number of nodes (which I have already accomplished)
2. Check whether new node + node count > 5 and, if so, prepend new node and remove last node. Otherwise, just add new node

How do you remove the last node? Here is my XML file structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RecentFiles>
   <File>
      <Path>Path goes here.</Path>
    </File>
</RecentFiles>
```

UPDATE:

The code below solves my issue with reading (as per advice of John), however, I still cannot figure out how to remove the last node when writing. I prefer not to use Linq in this case, so a solution using XmlReader is preferred, thanks.

```
XmlReader x = XmlReader.Create(this.PathToSpecialFolder + @"\" + Application.CompanyName + @"\" + Application.ProductName + @"\Recent.xml");

int c = 0;
while (x.Read())
{
    if (x.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && x.Name == "Path") 
    {
        c++;
        if (c <= 10)
        {
            MenuItem m = new MenuItem() { Header = x.ReadInnerXml() };
            m.Click += delegate
            {
            };
            openRecentMenuItem.Items.Add(m);
        }
    }
}
x.Close();

}
```

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Comment: Also, why not use LINQ to XML?